# Keeping a list on a same line

Tags: html, css, charts, grid-layout

I'm trying to make a list which should fit around 5 images per line, and if there are more, make a new line below and start to do that too. `float: left;` doesn't work because it messes EVERYTHING up.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>LolChamps - Knowledge Database</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/champions.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sansita+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Belleza' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>

<!-- NAVIGATION --> 
<div id="nav-bar">
    <div id="nav-bar-title">LoL Champs</div>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="champions">Champs</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Guides</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Model Viewer</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Lists</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Support</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- END NAVIGATION -->

<div id="main-body">
<div id="nav-body-divider"></div>

<p id="home-body-title">Champions</p>

<div id="champ-list">
<ul>

<li><a href="champs/aatrox.html"><img src="images/champion-icons/aatrox.png" /><br/><div id="champ-text">Aatrox</div></a></li>
<li><a href="champs/ahri.html"><img src="images/champion-icons/ahri.png" /><br/><div id="champ-text">Ahri</div></a></li>
<li><a href="champs/akali.html"><img src="images/champion-icons/Akali.png" /><br/><div id="champ-text">Akali</div></a></li>
<li><a href="champs/alistar.html"><img src="images/champion-icons/Alistar.png" /><br/><div id="champ-text">Alistar</div></a></li>
<li><a href="champs/amumu.html"><img src="images/champion-icons/amumu.png" /><br/><div id="champ-text">Amumu</div></a></li>
<li><a href="champs/anivia.html"><img src="images/champion-icons/anivia.png" /><br/><div id="champ-text">Anivia</div></a></li>
<li><a href="champs/annie.html"><img src="images/champion-icons/annie.png" /><br/><div id="champ-text">Annie</div></a></li>

</ul>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#champ-list {
    color: black;
    font-family: Arial;
}
#champ-list li {
    list-style-type: none;
    color: #B0B0B0;
}
#champ-list ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

As you can see I've tried `display: inline;` but to no avail. Here's an image of how I'm hoping it should turn out:

[image: This si what it should sort of look like.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
#champ-list ul li {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

You may need to adjust the width of your `li` so that 5 fit per line.

Answer (score 0):

`float: left` would work fine, it's probably causing issues because you're not [clearing your floats](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/), but using `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` is standard, in which case you should set the width of your `li`'s to 20% (or possibly less, you may need to play with it).